# How do I remove the soapy taste in homemade chili using home canned tomatoe juice?

Tags: flavor, sugar, canning

Used home canned juice and store bought tomatoes to make chili. Added 2 tbls of sugar to the chili to cut down the metal taste. Now my chili has a soapy after taste. Can thus be saved or should I dump it and start over?

Comment: A soapy taste is an unusual result for a chili, do you know if the taste came from the juice, canned tomatoes or something else?

Comment: Please edit and add your full recipe and method.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Your question is missing information that folks need in order to help you.  Please answer GdD's questions by edtiting your original question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is the soapy taste coming from the dishes (bowl) not getting sufficient rinsing in a dishwasher machine?